# How to rewrite url of an anchor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I have seen a [website](https://www.levangile.com/Bible-LSG-24-12-5-complet-Contexte-non.htm) where an anchored url has been rewritten and this facilitate Search engine optimization. For example to go to Jeremiah 12 Verse 5, when you check the html code you can just go to **#v5** like

> https://www.levangile.com/Affichage-Multi-Bible-Amp.php?Version=LSG&Livre=24&Chapitre=12&Verset=5&Contexte=non&Mode=complet#v5

However here you can access the same link as

> https://www.levangile.com/Bible-LSG-24-12-5-complet-Contexte-non.htm

And to go to verse 6 you can either go with a #v6 or

> https://www.levangile.com/Bible-LSG-24-12-6-complet-Contexte-non.htm

Here not only the page will scroll like an anchor to the verse but because the hastag of the anchor is passed as a Get method, the programmer is able to retrieve it and change the description of the page.

Therefore Jeremiah 12:5 will have it's own description while Jeremiah 12:6 will also have it's own description even though it is just an anchor.

My question is how to rewrite the url of an anchor.
if i have a url like `mypage.php#welcome` and `mypage.php#god` how do I rewrite the `Url` to `mypage-welcome` (and that will redirect to the hashtag `#welcome` on the same page and pass the welcome in a get method) same for the hashtag God ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely using some back end MVC pattern to control the webpage. In this type of scenario, the API will read and parse some of the html link into variables, and use them in the controller to render a 'view' through some sort of templating engine. This is not the only way to do this, but it is one of the most common.

Comment: I still don't get it. Practically what am I supposed to do ?